# A Puzzle Concerning an Extraordinary Quartet

Tags: knowledge, steganography, music

Did I tell you about what happened to me on December 24th?

Santa must have been in a rather enigmatic mood because he sent me a series of four notes.

First this:

> Iridescent diamond, ivory, gold and pearl.
>   You'll give me your baubles. You'll, celebrating, hurl.

Then this odd message:

> Aural leas, oh ear, we target.
>   Yea, on a date he ends era.

This was even stranger:

> I fear I'm dust. Pah! Hassle not.
>   Need is now: the itch he'd got.

Then last, this:

> Fear I stress, seeing we must pass
>   Through the rear to a secret mass

Altogether, quite a peculiar communication. At least I was able to figure out what he was going to give me for Christmas.

What is the message, and to what could it refer?

(In a belated spirit of giving, this question contains hints as to the nature of the gift, the makers of the gift, and the means of extracting the secret communication from the messages. Season's greetings.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How the message is hidden ...

> ... is hinted at in the sentences that introduce the notes. The message is hidden across all four notes and each note hides its part of the message in a different way.
>
>  Take the **first** letter of each word in the first note:
>
>      *I dig A Pygmy by Ch—*
>
>  Take all **odd** letters of the second note:
>
>      *—arles Hawtrey and the Dea—*
>
>  Take all **even** letters of the third note:
>
>      *—f Aids, Phase One in which Do—*
>
>  Take the **last** letter of each word of the fourth note:
>
>      *—ris gets her oats.*
>
>  Put together:
>
>      *I dig A Pygmy by Charles Hawtrey and the Deaf*
>      *Aids, Phase One in which Doris gets her oats.*
>
>  Apparently, John Lennon said this phrase at the beginning of the recording of [Two of Us](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_of_Us_(The_Beatles_song)), so perhaps the gift is the Beatles album [Let It Be](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_It_Be).

Comment: Congratulations! And a tip of the hat to the Fab Four. For those of us who remember vinyl, these are the first words you hear.